# Convert hex string to int in Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

I want to convert an hex string value in a variable to int.

This works for a literal: `"#{0xFF}".to_i`

But with a var...?

Not working test (interpolation error):

```
_myvar = "FF"
"#{0x_myvar}".to_i
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not check the [API documentation for String](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.20.3/String.html#to_i%28base%3AInt%3D10%2Cwhitespace%3Dtrue%2Cunderscore%3Dfalse%2Cprefix%3Dfalse%2Cstrict%3Dtrue%29-instance-method)

```
"FF".to_i(16)
```